# Remove xsi:type from generated xml when serializing

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, xml-serialization, cdata

I am sending XML externally.

One of the node called "datafield" has an element called "value". This may contain normal text content, or an html content (which I need to wrap in CData).

So, I created a base class (ProvisionDataField) with 2 classes inherits from it (ProvisionTextField, and ProvisionCDataField) as follows:

```
<XmlInclude(GetType(ProvisionTextField))>
<XmlInclude(GetType(ProvisionCDataField))>
Public MustInherit Class ProvisionDataField

    <XmlAttribute("datatype")>
    Public Property DataType As String

    <XmlElement("name")>
    Public Property Name As String

End Class

Public Class ProvisionCDataField
    Inherits ProvisionDataField

    <XmlIgnore()>
    Public Property ValueContent As String

    <XmlElement("value")>
    Public Property Value() As XmlCDataSection
        Get
            Dim doc As New XmlDocument
            Return doc.CreateCDataSection(ValueContent)
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As XmlCDataSection)
            ValueContent = value.Value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

Public Class ProvisionTextField
    Inherits ProvisionDataField

    <XmlElement("value")>
    Public Property Value As String

End Class
```

When I serialize,I get something like this:

```
   <entitydata entitytype="company">
      <datafield xsi:type="ProvisionTextField" datatype="string">
        <name>companyAcronym</name>
        <value>testCompany</value>
      </datafield>
      <datafield xsi:type="ProvisionCDataField" datatype="string">
        <name>ssocontent</name>
        <value><![CDATA[<html><body> HTML Content</body></html>]]></value>
      </datafield>
    </entitydata>
```

All good except that I've been told that I have to remove the "xsi:type" from the xml. So instead, I need my generated xml to look like this:

```
   <entitydata entitytype="company">
      <datafield datatype="string">
        <name>companyAcronym</name>
        <value>testCompany</value>
      </datafield>
      <datafield datatype="string">
        <name>ssocontent</name>
        <value><![CDATA[<html><body> HTML Content</body></html>]]></value>
      </datafield>
    </entitydata>
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Without the `xsi:type`, how would the recipient of the XML know which type was present?

Comment: Just to give more info, I am communicating to external services (written in Java) using POX (Plain Old XML). Rather than writing xml manually, I created classes and using xml serialization to generate the xml. The "type" is just the result of me using inheritance. The other system doesn't know at all about this type, and doesn't want it either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to overwrite xmlwriter.

[This blogpost](http://weblogs.asp.net/cazzu/archive/2004/01/23/62141.aspx) (not mine) shows you how.

Here is the VB.Net version.

```
Imports System.Xml.Serialization
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim p As New ProvisionCDataField()
        p.Name = "test"
        Dim sw1 = New StringWriter()
        Dim xs1 As New XmlSerializer(GetType(ProvisionDataField))
        xs1.Serialize(New XmlTextWriter(sw1), p)
        Console.WriteLine(sw1.ToString())
        Dim sw2 = New StringWriter()
        Dim xs2 As New XmlSerializer(GetType(ProvisionDataField))
        xs2.Serialize(New NonXsiTextWriter(sw2), p)
        Console.WriteLine(sw2.ToString())
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module

Public Class NonXsiTextWriter
    Inherits XmlTextWriter

    Public Sub New(ByVal w As TextWriter)
        MyBase.new(w)
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal w As Stream, ByVal encoding As Encoding)
        MyBase.new(w, encoding)
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal filename As String, ByVal encoding As Encoding)
        MyBase.new(filename, encoding)
    End Sub

    Dim _skip As Boolean = False

    Public Overrides Sub WriteStartAttribute(ByVal prefix As String, ByVal localName As String, ByVal ns As String)
        If localName = "xsi" Then
            _skip = True
            Return
        End If
        MyBase.WriteStartAttribute(prefix, localName, ns)
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Sub WriteString(ByVal text As String)
        If _skip Then Return
        MyBase.WriteString(text)
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Sub WriteEndAttribute()
        If _skip Then
            _skip = False
            Return
        End If
        MyBase.WriteEndAttribute()
    End Sub
End Class

<XmlInclude(GetType(ProvisionTextField))>
<XmlInclude(GetType(ProvisionCDataField))>
Public MustInherit Class ProvisionDataField

    <XmlAttribute("datatype")>
    Public Property DataType As String

    <XmlElement("name")>
    Public Property Name As String

End Class

Public Class ProvisionCDataField
    Inherits ProvisionDataField

    <XmlIgnore()>
    Public Property ValueContent As String

    <XmlElement("value")>
    Public Property Value() As XmlCDataSection
        Get
            Dim doc As New XmlDocument
            Return doc.CreateCDataSection(ValueContent)
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As XmlCDataSection)
            ValueContent = value.Value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

Public Class ProvisionTextField
    Inherits ProvisionDataField

    <XmlElement("value")>
    Public Property Value As String

End Class
```

With this as the result.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
 <ProvisionDataField xmlns:xsi="http://www .w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="ProvisionCDataField">
   <name>test</name><value><![CDATA[]]></value>
 </ProvisionDataField> 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
 <ProvisionDataField xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" d1p1:type="ProvisionCDataField"  xmlns:d1p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <name>test</name><value><![CDATA[]]></value>
 </ProvisionDataField>
```

Comment: You result still has the namespaces which the OP wanted to get rid of

Comment: -1 for showing an example of how to use `new XmlTextWriter()`, which has been deprecated since .NET 2.0.

Comment: @John it has not been deprecated but xmlwriter.create is now the prevered way of doing things http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter.aspx

Comment: That's a pretty strong claim John. I believe ObsoleteAttribute was introduced specifically to mark things as deprecated (not to mention the deprecated member list http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee471421.aspx). Less preferred != deprecated.

Comment: @JohnSaunders It's even still in the 4.5 framework, deprecated to me means they will remove it in one of the next versions, which they clearly are not doing.

Comment: "deprecated" doesn't mean "obsolete" or "removed". It means, "don't use _that_, use _this_ instead".

Comment: let's just get somethign clear. you're just saying that new-ing the class has been deprecated? why?

Comment: I have marked as answer, even though this answer does not 100% answer my question, but the link to the blog does. So, Thanks chrissie1. I have also added my own answer for reference.

Answer (score 3):

This is the answer I am looking for - it will ensure that the xsi:type resulted from XmlInclude attribute used in inheritance is omitted:

```
    ElseIf ns = XmlSchema.InstanceNamespace Then
        ' Omits all XSI attributes
        _skip = True
        Return
    End If
```

While this section will omit the xmlns:xsd and xmlns:xsi from the root

```
    If prefix = "xmlns" AndAlso (localName = "xsd" OrElse localName = "xsi") Then
        ' Omits XSD and XSI from root
        _skip = True
        Return
```

Full codes:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Schema

Public Class PlainXmlTextWriter
    Inherits XmlTextWriter

    Public Sub New(ByVal w As TextWriter)
        MyBase.new(w)
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal w As Stream, ByVal encoding As Encoding)
        MyBase.new(w, encoding)
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal filename As String, ByVal encoding As Encoding)
        MyBase.new(filename, encoding)
    End Sub

    Dim _skip As Boolean = False

    Public Overrides Sub WriteStartAttribute(ByVal prefix As String, ByVal localName As String, ByVal ns As String)
        If prefix = "xmlns" AndAlso (localName = "xsd" OrElse localName = "xsi") Then
            ' Omits XSD and XSI from root
            _skip = True
            Return
        ElseIf ns = XmlSchema.InstanceNamespace Then
            ' Omits all XSI attributes
            _skip = True
            Return
        End If
        MyBase.WriteStartAttribute(prefix, localName, ns)
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Sub WriteString(ByVal text As String)
        If _skip Then Return
        MyBase.WriteString(text)
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Sub WriteEndAttribute()
        If _skip Then
            _skip = False
            Return
        End If
        MyBase.WriteEndAttribute()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score -1):

No need to override XmlWriter, just use an instance of XmlSerializerNamespace:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim xSer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(MyType))

    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()

    Dim obj As MyType = getAnInstanceOfMyType()

    Using wrt As New StringWriter(sb)
        Dim ns As New XmlSerializerNamespaces
        ns.Add("", "")

        xSer.Serialize(wrt, obj, ns)

    End Using

    Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString())

    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

This will result in the xml having no namespaces at all.

EDIT:  Changed to VB code

EDIT 2:  Upon further testing, the test code I used only removed the namespace declarations from the resulting xml.  My original test did not produce the xsi:type attributes on the elements even though I used the classes provided by the OP, so I cannot determine if the code that I posted will remove them, as John Saunder alluded to in the comments.  I presumed that if the namespaces were removed, then the xsi:type attributes would also be removed, but the code I posted does not prove this.

Comment: I tested the code before posting and it seemed to work, the xsi type was removed.